# Can I affect properties of an Angular component based on change of other properties in a non-template-driven fashion?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing a form with Angular 6 and using some standart components, including [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) (I'd say that's a requirement). The form is supposed to have rather complicated logic (some field values affect other values or suggestions that ng-select should show). I have a rather general question (hoping that there's an approach which I haven't just found yet), but to stay more specific, let's consider the following example:

- I have 2 dictionaries (let's call them *categories* and *items*), each item being a "child" of a certain category
- I have to let user select a category and an item from each dictionary, for that I have 2 fields like

  ```
  <ng-select
    name="category"
    [items]="formSuggestions.categories$ | async"
    bindLabel="name"
    [(ngModel)]="formFields.category"
  ></ng-select>

  <ng-select
    name="item"
    [items]="formSuggestions.items$ | async"
    bindLabel="name"
    [(ngModel)]="formFields.item"
  ></ng-select>
  ```

  (in fact, they are wrapped into custom components which I omit for simplicity)
- (here `formSuggestions.items$` and `formSuggestions.categories$` are observables that are filled with suggestions on server response; each item is actually an object having `id`, `name` and `parentId`)
- what I need is: when a *category* is selected, suggestions for *items* are limited to those which are children of that category; when an *item* is selected, the *category* is set automatically

My question is: is there a way in Angular to "subscribe" to changes of one property in model (`formFields.item`) and apply it to others (`formFields.category`, `formSuggestions.categories$`) or the only way to deal with this is to set Outputs like `(change)` of each field?

The problem with that approach is the actual form is more complicated, for instance:

- there's another interface that should be shown in a modal window, where user can choose *category* (and same for *item*), so there's multiple points which change the props
- *item* selection should affect another ng-select's suggestions (for another field) and pre-fill some crud interface with default stuff for that item
- by the way, I have to show only 10 suggestions each time (suggestion dictionaries are quite long) and there's no "limit" option in ng-select, so I have to affect suggestion list based on field value
- ...

so I really wonder if I can go less template-driven. Any suggestions, at least for the 2 selections case?

Answer (score 1):

`(change)` is listening to the classical input change event (not Angular specific). See also [MDN-Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

For all `[(ngModel)]` bound elements, you could also use `(ngModelChange)` to listen to changes. Thats more Angular style. And it gets even more interesting when you create your own "input" components with the ControlValueAccessor.

The problem in your example is, that you use the subscribed suggestionCategories directly. You could (theoreticly) do a "map" in the observable stream and filter out the unwanted values. But this would only work for each emited event of the observable.

So in your case i fear you have to subscribe to the source, store the result in a component local variable.  You also copy the data in a second variable that you use to show the values on the UI.
And whenever the user selects a category, you take the original stored data, filter it and assign the filtered result to your second-variable.

HTML

```
<ng-select
  name="category"
  [items]="formSuggestions.categories$ | async"
  bindLabel="name"
  [(ngModel)]="formFields.category"
  (ngModelChange)="filterCategorySugestions($selectedValue)"
></ng-select>
```

In Typescript you would then use the `filterCategorySugestions` Method to filter the data and write it into your second variable (mentioned above).

by the way, when filtering, you could afterwards apply a `mylist.splice(10)` (standard Array method) to limit your results to the first 10. But perhaps you should ensure the order first. :-)

I hope it helps a bit.

warm regards
Jan

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try it this way; if it becomes clear that it's the most sane approach, I'll accept the answer too